# Android Method to Enable/Disable Touch Screen

Tags: android, button, touch, controls, screen

Hi there is thery any way to invoke a method that enables or disables the Touch Screen of Android?

I want this, because I have several buttons on my activity. When the user clicks on a button, it takes a few seconds to start the following activity, and because of that, while waiting that time, I don't want the user to be able to press anything.

I used a boolean that is True at start, then It changes to false when I click on the first button. And to every click on a button I check if the boolean is true...

But the problem is that Visually the user can click the button, it gets that look of being pressed..

So is there any good method that disables the entire touch screen ? And another that enables the entire touch screen ?

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: post the layout xml you have

Comment: what happens if the user has a device with on screen buttons and you disable the entire screen?

Comment: Guys it disable the buttons after on click, then changes activity.. if he comes back to the activity before, I want the touch screen available again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But the problem is that Visually the user can click the button, it gets that look of being pressed

Disable the buttons, using `setEnabled(false)`. This will not only prevent the user from clicking on them, but they will visually appear disabled, to let the user know that the user cannot click on them. It is important for the user to get the proper visual feedback about the buttons being disabled (and later enabled).

> is thery any way to invoke a method that enables or disables the Touch Screen of Android?

Not really.

Comment: Yes that was the solution I found a few seconds ago.. I use a for to run around all the childs of my view and disable all the buttons using the setEnable(false);

Thanks dude ;)